# Upgrading a Web Reference in a VB.Net Class Library Project

Tags: vb.net, wsdl, asmx

Our vendor has upgraded their SOAP Offering and we need to reference another WSDL file and change the url for the .asmx file to the newer versions.

What is the best way to do this with minimum breaking of the code?

It was referenced with a namespace as is typical.

Should I delete the existing web reference and add the new one using the same name?

Or should i change the 'web reference url' url to the new one and simply update it?

Any ideas / solutions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was my solution:

I changed the 'Web Reference URL' of the folder in Web References to the new WSDL

I then right clicked the folder and clicked 'Update Web Reference'

And it changed all of the files that were expected